# Monta um vetor com 5 alunos,no quinto aluno este vetor multiplica por 2,podendo dar entrada a 10

Tags: java

```
private Aluno alunos[];
private int ultimaPosicao;
public int tam=5;
/**
 * Construtor 
 */
public VetorDeAlunos(){
    alunos = new Aluno[tam];
    ultimaPosicao = 0;
} 
/**
 * Metodo para inserir aluno na lista. Este metodo insere o aluno na ultima posiçao
 * disponivel
 * @params  Aluno aluno - Aluno a ser inserido no vetor.
 * 
 */
public void inserir(Aluno aluno){                
    //o array estoura aqui    
    this.alunos[ultimaPosicao] = aluno;
    ultimaPosicao++;        
}
```

//nesse algorimo tem varias classes de teste outras de botoes e etc... (FEITO NO GREENFOOT)

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida? Qual o problema no código?

Comment: o array estoura em this.alunos[ultimaPosicao] = aluno;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expandir o tamanho do array é impossível.

O que você pode fazer é reatribuir a variável `alunos` com um novo array de dimensão maior baseado nos valores antigos através do método `copyOf()` da classe `java.util.Arrays`:

```
public void inserir(Aluno aluno){                
    //o array estoura aqui    
    this.alunos[ultimaPosicao] = aluno;
    ultimaPosicao++;
    if(ultimaPosicao == 5) {
        alunos = Arrays.copyOf(alunos, 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que por um Se `ultimaPosicao == 5` então

```
private Aluno alunosnovos[] = new Aluno[10];
alunosnovos = alunos;
alunos = alunosnovos;
```

motivo voce tem que aumentar o espaço fisico copiar os antigo para o novo espaço e então copiar de volta;

voce precisar fazer o espaço crescer antes de tentar adicionar novos elementos ou não funciona. entende?

Comment: entendo amigo ,ja tentei da mesma forma ,mas nao funciona , continua com o mesmo erro...